# Where can I find iOS 13 simulators for iPhone X, Xs, Xr to test Dark Mode?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, ios13

I need to make screenshots for 6.5" screens in iTunesconnect. I want to show them in dark mode. However, the only iOS 13 simulators in Xcode 11.2 seen to be for iPhone 8.

Where can I find simulators for iPhone Xs with 6.5" screens running iOS 13?

Comment: Windows => Device and simulators => add (on bottom left corner) => add the desired simulator and wait for download

And for dark mode on the storyboard you can choose the "interface style" to "dark"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Go to Window -> Devices & Simulators (or press  ⇧⌘2)

Check if there are some iOS simulators on the list - if yes, then select checkbox `Show as run destination`:
[image]

If these simulators are missing, you can click + button on left bottom corner and create new simulator:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Michcio. The iPhone 11 Pro Max simulator with Xcode v11.2 is running iOS 13. With other devices you can see the iOS version in the list of run targets, but the ones that don't show the version, you solution is handy.